# Finding Questions With Delete Votes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, data-explorer, vote-to-delete

As a mod on RPG.SE, I'd like to be able to find questions with extant delete votes, either in the site search or in the Review section if the Review section didn't remove questions with delete votes whenever one person reviewed them. (I wish it worked like that with close votes too actually, if a question with one close vote gets reviewed and gets a second close vote, then it's gone from the review queue - that helped how? Our users are pretty on top of the review queues but for multivote actions that then deprives mods and other users of further review action).

We don't have SO numbers of users, so it's very unusual for a question to get enough delete votes to really delete it (especially given that you have to be on motivated post-close cleanup duty to get around to it). Usually on our site if a question has 2 or more delete votes it's unquestionably trash. I'd like to be able to go look at questions with outstanding delete votes to see if they need mod-deleting.

Comment: go to Programmers.SE chat (Whiteboard room), ask MichaelT - he posted SEDE script there to look for questions having delete votes (I tried it once, works like a charm... except that most of the questions it found had my vote already:)

Answer (score 6):

[This](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/143162/list-of-top-count-questions-having-delete-votes-which-are-not-yet-deleted-by-vo) is the query that gnat mentioned in the comments.  A nice feature of it is that you can specify how many results you want returned.

It was originally written by Shadow Wizard and MichaelT updated it so you could filter by number of votes needed.

Comment: +1, this will be really helpful for Code Golf and other beta sites!

Comment: This is very helpful - IMO it should be actual mod functionality though! I appreciate SEDE scripts but that's a stopgap for a better integrated implementation.

Answer (score 4):

There's this query to find questions with a single delete vote left:

https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/141131/list-of-questions-with-only-1-remaining-delete-vote-required-to-delete

Just comment out the `- COUNT(v.VoteTypeId)=1` part to get them by delete votes left to be removed.