# SEDE Query to find posts I have cast delete vote on but aren't yet deleted?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, vote-to-delete

Related to [10k "Most Delete Votes" List - Don't Show Questions I Can't Vote For](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44101/10k-most-delete-votes-list-dont-show-questions-i-cant-vote-for), I'd like to be able to identify posts I've cast delete votes on, but which aren't yet deleted.

My intention is to modify the queries reference in [Finding Questions With Delete Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230470/finding-questions-with-delete-votes) to filter the result to filter out questions I've already voted on from the results.

I see nothing in the database schema that support this; can we have access to that information?

If a SEDE query isn't possible, as per [@Glorfindel's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305347/#comment992518_305347), is there a way I can get that info another way, perhaps something I can pick up via a user script? I've tried this, but the only clue available afaict is that the text on the "delete" link changes to say "You have voted...", but that's as a result of hovering.

Comment: All votes (except bounties and favorites) are anonymized before they're put into SEDE. That means you cannot filter these out with a pure SEDE solution.

Comment: Awesome, closing it as status-declined then ;)

Comment: @rene **Declined** you do not have the authority to add this tag.

Comment: How about scraping https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=deletion

Comment: @rene That's got some promise!

Comment: @mogsdad Given that the information you're wanting is not directly available (other than by scraping the pages rene suggested), it may be beneficial to step back a bit (i.e. what are you ultimately attempting to achieve may be possible through other means). So, what's your real goal (i.e. what are you intending to use the information for)?

Comment: @Makyen To support burnination, I want to produce a "delete vote queue" thingy (that's the technical term, I believe), that would present a user with questions with a target tag that (a) have 1+ delete votes and (b) require 1+ delete votes to be deleted and (c) the user has not already voted on. This question is about part c.

Comment: That's very close to what [Magic™ Tag Review 2](https://github.com/makyen/Tiny-Giant-myuserscripts/blob/master/MagicTagReview2.user.js) already has the capability to do. I've made changes to it so it auto-skips questions which the user has already voted on (actually, you can choose to skip: after voting, those you've voted on, closed, deleted, etc.). I need to clean that part up and submit a PR, but the already existing functionality allows you to filter the tag for # delete-votes (and a whole bunch of other things).

Comment: @Makyen I'm using MTR2 v1.0.1.2 (latest, Sept 11 2017), and while it _usually_ marks questions a user has close-voted, it does not do anything to identify delete-voted questions yet. That's what I was looking to change - if you're already on it, great!

Comment: @Mogsdad, Yeah, I need to do a PR. I worked on it after mentioning it here. I realized I hadn't actually added the forced check for the user having delete-voted. I added it in. User delete-vote status is now fetched for each closed question viewed and the question skipped when the user has voted, if the user has selected to do so. I should have a PR for MTR2 today with the auto-skip changes and a various others. I'm interested in the *usually* wrt. marking CV'ed questions. Have you identified a repeatable case where a question the user has CV'ed isn't marked (or a hint as to circumstances)?

Comment: @Mogsdad, OK, finally submitted [the PR for this in MTR2](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/pull/22).